# ZephyrOS: how to add driver module to out of tree project

Tags: zephyr-rtos

I haven't found a definitive info on how to add a driver module to out-of-tree Zephyr project, so I will provide the answer by my own.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Changes:**

*CMakeLists.txt*

```diff
+set(ZEPHYR_EXTRA_MODULES drivers/ololo)
find_package(Zephyr REQUIRED HINTS $ENV{ZEPHYR_BASE})
```

*prj.conf*

```diff
+CONFIG_OLOLO=y
```

*Kconfig*

> No changes

**New files:**

*drivers/ololo/CMakeLists.txt*

```python
zephyr_library()
zephyr_library_sources_ifdef(CONFIG_OLOLO ololo.c)
```

*drivers/ololo/Kconfig*

```kconfig
menuconfig OLOLO
        bool "Ololo driver"
        default y
        select BLAH
        depends on MEH
        help
          Enable support for ololo driver

if OLOLO

module = OLOLO
module-str = ololo
source "subsys/logging/Kconfig.template.log_config"

endif
```

*drivers/ololo/ololo.c*

```c
/* Code goes here */
```

*drivers/ololo/zephyr/module.yml*

```yaml
build:
  cmake: .
  kconfig: Kconfig
```

Answer (score 0):

To add a custom driver module that specifically includes **system calls**, one may want to take a look at [teslabs/zds-2022-drivers-app](https://github.com/teslabs/zds-2022-drivers-app/) *lock* module driver.